# gradle plugin with kotlin - set boolean extension property

Tags: gradle, kotlin, gradle-plugin

I am trying to migrate a gradle plugin from groovy to kotlin. I have a boolean `Property` that I would like to initialize to false in my plugin extension:

```
open class MyPluginExtension(project: Project) {

    val myBooleanProperty: Property<Boolean> = project.objects.property(Boolean::class.java)

    init {
        myBooleanProperty.set(false)
    }
}
```

This fails with

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot set the value of a property of type boolean using an instance of type java.lang.Boolean.
```

The exception is thrown in `org.gradle.api.internal.provider.DefaultPropertyState#set(T)`

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Looks like a bug, have you searched on https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl/issues to see if it's been already filed?

Answer (score 1):

`Boolean::class.java` in Kotlin refers to the primitive type. Try specifying the Object type instead:

```
val myBooleanProperty: Property<Boolean> = project.objects.property(Boolean::class.javaObjectType)
```

Comment: Yes that is probably the reason. I cannot verify your answer anymore because the project has gone into a different direction in the meantime.